# Get React Native bottomTabNavigator Height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need access to the height of a bottom tab navigator created through  `createBottomTabNavigator` so that I can layout my components snugly within my screen. What is the straight forward method for accessing that in my component?

```
function App({navigation}) {
    const tabBarHeight = "???";
}
const Nav = createBottomTabNavigator({
    {App: App},
    {initialRouteName: "App"},
})
export default createAppContainer(Nav);
```

Comment: Have seen this [solution](https://github.com/react-navigation/tabs/issues/97#issuecomment-545842090)?

Comment: @igor.codes Yes. That is not ideal because it requires the component to rerender if I want to use the nav bar height in calculating other components style. What I'm looking for is a solution that would allow me to access the height before the component renders for the first time. Also it requires a lot of additional code just for fetching the height. Requires overwriting of the TabBarComponent which I'm not currently doing.